# How to retrieve data from DynamoDB via a column other than the Primary ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get the data by address on the table.

[image: table]

I'm working on Express environment.

Could you help me with how can I get the data by address, not primary ID?

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving data from DynamoDB by using a non-key attribute is not possible. You can define a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on your address field. Since addresses are not unique, your best bet might be to construct a complex global secondary index consisting of:

- Partition Key: `address`
- Sort Key: `ID`

That way your global secondary index is unique (because the combination of address and ID is unique) and you can query your global secondary index for a specific address, which will return all records with that address.